# How do HashSet and HashMap work in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I'm a bit confused about the internal implementation of `HashSet` and `HashMap` in java.

This is my understanding, so please correct me if I'm wrong:

Neither `HashSet` or `HashMap` allow duplicate elements.

`HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, so in a `HashSet` when we call `.add(element)`, we are calling the `hashCode()` method on the element and internally doing a `put(k,v)` to the internal `HashMap`, where the key is the `hashCode` and the value is the actual object. So if we try to add the same object to the `Set`, it will see that the `hashCode` is already there, and then replace the old value by the new one.

But then, this seems inconsistent to me when I read how a `HashMap` works when storing our own objects as keys in a `HashMap`. 
In this case we must override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods and make them consistent between each other, because, if we find keys with the same `hashCode`, they will go to the same bucket, and then to distinguish between all the entries with the same `hashCode` we have to iterate over the list of entries to call the method `equals()` on each key and find a match. 
So in this case, we allow to have the same `hashCode` and we create a bucket containing a list for all the objects with the same `hashCode`, however using a `HashSet`, if we find already a `hashCode`, we replace the old value by the new value.

I'm a bit confused, could someone clarify this to me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct regarding the behavior of `HashMap`, but you are wrong about the implementation of `HashSet`.

`HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap` internally, but the element you are adding to the `HashSet` is used as the key in the backing `HashMap`. For the value, a dummy value is used. Therefore the `HashSet`'s `contains(element)` simply calls the backing `HashMap`'s `containsKey(element)`.

Answer (score 0):

The value we **insert** in HashMap acts as a Key to the map object and for its value, java uses a **constant variable**.So in the **key-value pair**, all the **keys** will have the **same value**.

you can refer to this link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Hash Map:-Basically Hash map working as key and value ,if we want to store data as key and value pair then we will go to the hash map, basically  when we insert data by using hash map  basically internally it will follow 3 think,
1.hashcode
2..equale
3.==

when we insert the data in hash map it will store the data in bucket(fast in) by using hash  code , if there is 2 data store in the same bocket then **key collision** will happen to resolve this key collision we use (==) method, always == method check the reference of the object, if both object  hashcode is same then first one replace to second one if the hashcode is not same then **hashing Collision** will happen  to resolve this hashing collision we will use (.equal) method .equal method basically it will check the content , if both the content is same then it will return true other wise it will return false, so in the hash map it will check is the content is same ? if the content is same then first one replace to the second one if both content is different the it will create another one object in the bocket and store the data

Answer (score 0):

Hash Set:- Basically Hash Set is use to store bunch of object at a time ,internally hash set also use hash map only , when we insert somethink by using add method internally it will call put method and it will store data in the hashmap key bcz  hash map key always unique and duplicate are not allowed that's way hashset also  unique and duplicate are not allowed and if we entered duplicate also in hashst it will not through any exception first one will replace to the second one and in the value it will store constant data "PRESENT".

You can observe that internal hashmap object contains the element of hashset as keys and constant “PRESENT” as their value.
Where present is constant which is defined as 
private static final Object present = new Object()